# Audio from another website

Tags: javascript, java, php, html

I am trying to play music from [Dubtrack](https://dubtrack.fm/paradisemusic) in the background of my website. I cannot use it as an audio track as I want it to play only when someone is playing music there. I have tried using an invisible iframe but it gives me this error:

Refused to display 'https://www.dubtrack.fm/join/paradisemusic' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

If you know anyway to do this that would be amazing. Also, I don't want the video I just want the audio.

Regards,
Dan

Comment: As an aside, background music on a website is generally considered [poor user experience](http://completeusability.com/regrettable-background-music/).

Comment: Meh, @Steve it's for a reason :3

Comment: That's fine, just pointing it out.

Comment: That's quite different because of XSS protections. Are you able to get the music as a file and play it so?

Comment: @mstruebing Sadly not.